# Добрый день, можно ли использовать addEventListener во Vue?, просто нужно подписаться на скролл, пока не знаю как если без addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, прокрутка

можно ли использовать addEventListener во Vue?, просто нужно подписаться на скролл, пока не знаю как если без addEventListener?

Answer (score 0):

1. Vue.js — JavaScript-фреймворк.Там можно писать как на JS так и на Vue
2. На Vue как я помню можно сделать scroll
   https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html